# Question about credit card

Tags: credit, interest-rate

My credit card due date is May 4th and the closing date is May 7th.
I have paid statement balance in full today, so it's early than the due date. But I would like to continue purchase through this credit card.  Do I still need to pay this part of statement balance before the due date and if not will I be charged interest fees?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you should not. As long as you paid an amount equal to the April 7th statement balance, there will be no interest due. Any charges made since April 7th will go on the May 7th statement, and you will have until June 4th to pay those charges with no interest due - as long as you pay the entire May 7th statement balance.